# confidence interval and hypothesis testing problem

Tags: statistics

You want to test the durability of a new type of white paint for marking asphalt crosswalks in a city. By automatic electronic meters installed in eight pedestrian crossing areas (where previously had been painted white lines with the painting), the number of motor vehicles that passed before the lines begin to erase recorded. The results were as follows: 149400, 162000, 133700, 126400, 108300, 136500, 167800 and 142600.

a) Determine a confidence interval of 95% for the average number of vehicles that can withstand the paint before beginning to fade.

b) What sample size should be used if desired estimate the average number of vehicles that can withstand the paint before starting to fade with less error of 1000 cars for a confidence level of 99%?

c) Test the hypothesis that the average number of vehicles that can withstand the paint before start to fade is more than 15,000 vehicles. Use  $\alpha = 0.01$

can you help me with the subparagraph b)?, I think I have to use $3.49948=\alpha = 0.01$ for n-1=7 for the t-table, Im correct? or i have to asumme is a normal distribution?, and for the subparagraph c), It's the same?  $3.49948=\alpha = 0.01$ for n-1=7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) There are no outliers so it is reasonable to use a 95% t-CI 
of the form $\bar X \pm t^* S/\sqrt{n},$ where $t^*$ cuts 2.5%
probability from the upper tail of Student's t distribution
with $df = n - 1 = 7.$ This amounts to
$(124762, 156913).$

```
 x = c(149400, 162000, 133700, 126400, 108300, 136500, 167800, 142600)
 n = length(x);  a = mean(x);  s = sd(x);  se = s/sqrt(n);  t.c = qt(.975, n-1)
 n; a; s; se; t.c
 ## 8
 ## 140837.5
 ## 19228.47
 ## 6798.291
 ## 2.364624
 a + c(-1,1)*qt(.975, n-1)*s/sqrt(n)
 ## 124762.1 156912.9
```

[image]

(b) The margin of error is $t^*s/\sqrt{n},$ so
$n \approx (t^* s/ 19228)^2.$ This is a little messy
because $t^*$ depends on $n.$ But it seems sure that
$n > 30,$ so $t^*$ is essentially stable near 2.
So it seems that 1480 cars would suffice. This is
quite speculative because $S$ is not a reliable
estimate of $\sigma$ with only $n = 8$ observations.

(c) It seems to me that you want to test $H_0: \mu \ge 15,000$
against the $one$-sided alternative $H_a: \mu < 15,000.$
Notice that $\bar X = 14,0837.5$ and the question is
whether this is significantly smaller than 150,000. I guess you must
mean 150,000, not 15,000. (Also, you wouldn't be concerned if the paint withstands
$more$ than 15,000 vehicles.)

Then you will reject if $T = \frac{140,837.5 - 150,000}{S/\sqrt{n}} < -c,$ where $c = 2.998$ cuts 1% probability from the upper tail of (the symmetrical) Student's t distribution with $df = 7.$

```
 t.test(x, alte="less", mu=150000)

 ##         One Sample t-test

 ## data:  x 
 ## t = -1.3478, df = 7, p-value = 0.1099
 ## alternative hypothesis: true mean is less than 150000 
 ## 95 percent confidence interval:
 ##      -Inf 153717.4 
 ## sample estimates:
 ## mean of x 
 ##  140837.5
```

Notes: (1) Texts use various notations to denote cut-off points
from Student's t and other distributions. Some of them are more
sensible than others, but your notation
$3.49948 = \alpha = 0.01$ is transparently wrong. (2) This
problem would probably be easier to think about if you
moved the decimal place and talked of thousands of vehicles,
rather than individual ones.

Comment: very helpful, thanks!